# MsTest does not copy native dlls

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest

I have a unit test and use A.dll. A.dll internally uses a_native_version_1.dll which is a native dll written in C. The dependency is like below:

`App` -> `A.dll` -> `a_native_version_1.dll.`

I know that [DeploymentItemAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx) can be used to solve this problem but dll's name has version in it. So, if we upgrade the dll to version 2 then the name will be a_native_version_2.dll and we have to change the tests.

Is there an alternative and nicer way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the post build actions, and add a copy a_native_version* task. Or update the references of the project each time your dll changes name.